# timer function in django that self executes on user input

Tags: django

I want to render an html page after a particular amount of time that I am getting through user as input. So what I am thinking is there would be some timer function that would be executing. But the problem is where to keep that function in django. It is important for the function to execute at that exact time. And time starts as soon as the user gives the input of amount of time.

Comment: It's impossible to help you to complete what you want because you didn't show us any code, but most likely you would use javascript to complete this. You just use javascript to capture the user input and trigger your system to count the time.

Answer (score 0):

Noobish solution, I'm assuming you are using class based views.
Also, counter ain't exact. Starts after submition with server communication and processing lags.

**views.py**

```
from time import sleep
class MyView(View):
    def get(self[...]):
        """render page with time input"""

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sleep(request.POST['user_time_inputfield_id'])
        """do stuff here"""
```

notice that sleep method input is in seconds, so do the appropriate conversion if needed.
time docs, it includes considerations on precision.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html